# What are the possible solutions to make an application compatible with updated versions of Windows from XP to 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net

Regarding the use of .NET Framework versions, what are the possible solutions to make an application compatible with updated versions (only with high-priority and important updates - not the optional updates because they may or may not be installed) of Windows from XP to 8.1?

Comment: I don't understand the question - if you are writing a .NET application you are (typically) targeting a version of the framework, not a specific version of Windows (unless you are using P/Invoke or similar). Please can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: If i want my application to be compatible with updated Windows XP and above, what are my solutions regarding the choice of .NET Framework versions? For instance, i know i can target Framework 4 in my project, bundle Framework 4 installer with my application installer, and that way it my application should work in all Windows versions from XP to 8.1 (i hope). The question is about what are the other possible solutions... for instance one may prefer to what separate versions  of the program to different versions of Windows instead of force the installation of some Net Framework version.

Comment: What is the reason behind the famous 'Compatibility Issue' in Windows then?

Answer (score 0):

An application written in .NET C# should always be compatible with any version of windows that has the .NET Framework installed, there's only a small difference between the .NET Framework Client and Full versions (Has to do with certain features that the client version doesn't have, see it as a lightweight version of the .NET Framework, also since 4.5 it is discontinued => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)